# simpleXML_load_file does not work

Tags: php, xampp

i use this php commands in localhost.

```
$bookXML = simpleXML_load_file($bookURL,'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
if($bookXML== FALSE)
         echo "FALSE";
```

The variable $bookURL is a link:

```
http://127.0.0.1/funtrain/resa2/./php/makebooking.php?excode=GR CAN&ticknum=28084&date=2013-05-10&salesman=ALEXANDRA&name=.&adults=2&children=0&infants=0&price1=16&price2=8&pickup=Z_ALEX&time=11:40:00&hotel=Z_ALEX&remarks=&bigremarks=&trf1=0&tax1=0&trf2=0&tax2=0
```

The link works in browser and return:

```
<book_reference><number>19793</number></book_reference>
```

The "simpleXML_load_file" return false...
I use `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` but do not return anything.

Can anybody help me. I use Xampp v3.1.0.1.0 in windows7 64bit

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is this dot here ...resa2/'.'/php/makebooking.php...

Comment: please do var_dump($bookXML)

Comment: It 's nothing... i deleted!

Comment: It returns bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

**simpleXML_load_file** needs a path to the (local) XML file as first Parameter, not a URL

Comment: But it is a php script that export the xml code.
i forgot to tell you that it works online...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$bookXML = simpleXML_load_file($bookURL,'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
if($bookXML=== FALSE){
  echo "FALSE";
}else{

}
```

Comment: Why do you think this will change anything?